# MongoDB document naming

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have tried so many time different things but unable understand that whenever I am saving data into MongoDB why am I getting the name of that document as below

**User.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    require: true,
    unique: true,
    lowercase: true,
  },
  username: {
    type: String,
    require: true,
    unique: true,
    maxLength: 7,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    require: true,
    minLength: 8,
  },
});

const User = mongoose.model("user", userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

When I have saved the data by hitting API through postman and printing the data in console, the data I am receiving is as below:

```json
    email {
        _id: new ObjectId("627a4ae94b8958e3fe968311"),
        email: 'abc@abc.com',
        username: 'fzee07',
        password: 'test1234',
        __v: 0
      }
```

So my question is this that why this object is getting saved and named as **"email"**.

**registerUser.js**

```
const User = require("../../models/User");

const registerUser = async (req, res) => {
  const { email, username, password } = req.body;

  try {
    const e_mail = await User.findOne({});
    console.log("email", e_mail);
    if (e_mail.email === email) {
      res.status(409).json({
        success: false,
        msg: "User already exists",
      });
    } else {
      if (username.length < 8) {
        if (password.length >= 8) {
          const user = User.create({ email, username, password });
          res.status(201).json({
            success: true,
            data: "User Created",
          });
        } else {
          res.status(401).json({
            success: false,
            data: "Password muste be minimum 8 characters",
          });
        }
      } else {
        res.status(401).json({
          success: false,
          data: "Username must be less than 8 characters",
        });
      }
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};

module.exports = registerUser;
```

Comment: If any suggestions in editing the question kindly help me to edit. Please do not mark down the question. That may help you profile but someone may not be able to upgrade, if you don't help in learning others

Comment: 1. Try to do the validations within Mongoose hooks such as `pre('save')` and `pre('update')` to clean up your route's code :D

Comment: 2. Can you show the route where you find and return an already created user from the db?

Comment: @mstephen19, I really couldn't understand both of your reply. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: 1. [Docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#pre). Use Mongoose middleware to handle your validations rather than having a bunch of nested if...elses within your route function which make it difficult to read.

Comment: 2. The code you're showing is creating a user. The issue you're having is when you hit the route that returns a user object from the database. Can we see that code?

Comment: I got it. very thankful for you actually I found the issue. In DB it is not giving any name to that object it is me who is printing by giving a name "email"

Comment: @mstephen19 bro this is the only logic written behind the route so far. There is no other logic or middlewares are added. Though very thanks for providing the Docs above

Answer (score 1):

I understand the problem now. Sorry about the confusion, I misread the second part of your question. The reason you're getting this in console:

```
email {
    _id: new ObjectId("627a4ae94b8958e3fe968311"),
    email: 'abc@abc.com',
    username: 'fzee07',
    password: 'test1234',
    __v: 0
  }
```

Is because you are console logging the string `"email"`, then your user object from the database, which you have confusingly named `e_mail`.

Change the log message to look like this, and you're good:

```
console.log("user", e_mail);
```

In fact, your code needs some severe refactoring. Right now, it's not very readable. Here's an improvement:

```
const User = require('../../models/User');

const registerUser = async (req, res) => {
    const { email, username, password } = req.body;

    try {
        // Find a user with that email
        const user = await User.findOne({ email });
        console.log('user', user);

        // if it exists, return
        if (user) {
            res.status(409).json({
                success: false,
                message: 'User already exists',
            });
            return;
        }

        // Validate the username and password
        // If validates, create the user
        if (username.length < 8 && password.length >= 8) {
            const newUser = User.create({ email, username, password });

            res.status(201).json({
                success: true,
                message: 'User created',
                data: newUser,
            });
            return;
        }

        // If all else fails, return 401
        res.status(401).json({
            success: false,
            message: 'Username must be less than 8 characters & password must be at least 8 characters long',
        });
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({
            success: false,
            message: 'Server error',
        });
    }
};

module.exports = registerUser;
```

I changed all the places where you had the key of `data` to have the key of `message`, as messages were the values.

Once again though, I really recommend doing the validation in Mongoose middleware/hooks instead of right within the route. Will save you headaches as your application grows.

Comment: Sure man, will definitely take you recommendations and will apply. Again very thankful of you. It really helped especially in writing the readable codes.